# Any tips for debugging or tracing your program in the development process?

Tags: debugging, logging, trace

I've been programming for quite some time and I've never been able to make consistent ways of debugging or tracing my program. So far in Java and C# I've been working with the console and simply use System.out in java or Console in C#.

However, I have not much experience with actually deploying a program or "selling" it but I think it's not a proper way to have like Console.WriteLine() everywhere.

I would like to know if there are other methods. I was thinking of using a logger and write it to a text file which uses a debug variable to write or not based on severance (like php E_ALL etc.) or have an active multi-line textbox active that shows everything.

However, the first method will not allow me to view it directly and I have to open the file after the program shuts down as it can't write to an open file. The second method is real-time but it closes with the program.

Is there a nice way of somehow combining this? Should I write an external app that reads/closes/waits for updates from a log file and then shows it to me? Or is the console the way to go? I could add a custom class that only permits logging when debugging.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Search Google for "Loggin framework" and your favorite language and you'll probably find something that answers your need.

For Java, you'll probably want to go with [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/), and for C# you have [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html). There are many more options if you don't like these particular two.